# c++ string search functions

Tags: c++, string

I have the functions:

```
    bool specialChk(string a) 
{
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++)
        {
            if (a[i] == '`' || a[i] == '~' || a[i] == '!' || a[i] == '@' || a[i] == '#' || a[i] == '$' || a[i] == '%' || a[i] == '^' || a[i] == '&' || a[i] == '*' || a[i] == '(' || a[i] == ')' || a[i] == '-' || a[i] == '_' || a[i] == '=' || a[i] == '+' || a[i] == '[' || a[i] == ']' || a[i] == '{' || a[i] == '}' || a[i] == ';' || a[i] == ':' || a[i] == '\'' || a[i] == '"' || a[i] == ',' || a[i] == '<' || a[i]== '>' || a[i] == '.' || a[i] == '/' || a[i] == '?' || a[i] == '|' || a[i] == '\\')
                return true;
        }
    }

bool digitChk(string a)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++)
    {
        if (a[i] == '1' || a[i] == '2' || a[i] == '3' || a[i] == '4'|| a[i] == '5' || a[i] == '6' || a[i] == '7' || a[i] == '8' || a[i] == '9' || a[i] == '0')
            return true;
    }

}

int symbolChk(string a) // combining symbol checks
{
    if (specialChk(a) && digitChk(a))
        return 2;
    else if (specialChk(a) || digitChk(a))
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

and no matter the string passed through, it is always returning 2.
Anyone have any idea why?

Comment: holy line length batman

Answer (score 3):

**You forgot to `return false` on failure.**

That doesn't happen automatically; your return value is unspecified in that case. In fact, your entire program has undefined behaviour as a result.

```
bool specialChk(string a) // ← are you sure you don't want `const string& a`?
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
        if (/* omg at least wrap this */)
            return true;
    }

    return false;  // ← here!
}
```

Same for `digitChk`.

Comment: I was told not to return false inside of the for loop cause that causes issues too, It worked going outside of the loop though, thank you.

Comment: @Garret: Obviously, returning false _inside_ the loop would result in only the first element ever being checked (and let's avoid vaguities like "that causes issues" from now on). That doesn't mean you don't have to return at all.

Comment: Great answer. Re: 'omg atleast wrap this', it would probably be significantly cleaner to define the characters in a compile time array and turn the if statement into a for+if. That would also assist maintainability, if chars were to be added or removed.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this too.

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool specialChk(string a) {
    String checkList = "`~!@#$%^&*()-_=+[]{};:\'\",<>./?|\\";

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
        if(checkList.find(a[i]))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool digitChk(string a) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
        if (a[i] >= 48 && a[i] <= 57)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int symbolChk(string a) // combining symbol checks
{
    if (specialChk(a) && digitChk(a))
        return 2;
    else if (specialChk(a) || digitChk(a))
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```